# Why is this pandas data frame not callable

Tags: python-3.x

Newbie trying to create some graphs and don't know why these dataframes aren't callable. help.

```
loc="math edx review\Automobile_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(loc)

def plot_hist(auto_prices, cols, bins=10):
    for col in cols:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))#plot area
        ax = fig.gca()#define axis
        auto_prices[col].plot.hist(ax=ax, bins=bins)
        counts=auto_prices[col].valuecounts()
        counts.plot.bar(ax=ax, bins=bins)
        ax.set_title('hist of' + col)
        ax.set_xlabel(col)
        ax.set_ylabel('number of autos')
        plt.show()
plot_cols=['curb_weight', 'engine_size', 'city_mpg','price']
#callable(plot_cols)
#callable(df)
plot_hist(df, plot_cols)
```

> 'module' object is not callable

Comment: can you try replacing `fig.gca()` with `plt.gca()`

Comment: use:import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,   not: import matplotlib as plt